# Is Gzip supposed to honor original filename during decompress?

Tags: compression, archiving, filenames, gzip

This question stems from a Crypto++ library question on Stack Overflow: [How to add filename to archive if compressing using Gzip class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27739140/608639).

Gzip, as specified in [RFC 1952](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt) has an optional field for the original filename:

```
  (if FLG.FNAME set)

     +=========================================+
     |...original file name, zero-terminated...| (more-->)
     +=========================================+
```

If the `FNAME` bit is set in the flag field, then the original filename is present.

We added the feature to Crypto++ and tested it on OS X. On OS X, it seems the `gzip` program, The Unarchiver (the default archive program), and the [Archive Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-archive-browser/id510232205?mt=12) (App Store purchase) do not honor the original filename. That is, each decompresses to a filename which is the archive name sans the `gz` extension; and not the original filename as it appears in the header.

For example, here's an image under the [Archive Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-archive-browser/id510232205?mt=12). The original filename field is set to `test-filename.txt`, but the tool shows the filename as `gzip-test`, and unpacks it to a file named `gzip-test`:

[image]

`GZip` (and `Gunzip`) is *not* an IEEE standard [Unix Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unix_commands), so I can't really figure out where to seek knowledge on the expected behavior.

Is this expected behavior? Or am I seeing a bug in three different programs?

If its expected, then what practical purpose does the original filename serve?

Comment: Related: here's the bug report for The Unarchiver and The Archive Browser: [Issue 802: The Archive Browser does not honor original filename field in a GZIP header](http://code.google.com/p/theunarchiver/issues/detail?id=802).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [gzip man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/gzip.html), using the `-N` or `--name` option when using `gunzip` recovers the original file name. `-N` is the default when compressing (so `gzip` always saves the original file name) but not when decompressing so it has to be used explicitly with `gunzip`.

I tested this as follows:

```
$ ls
test.txt

$ gzip test.txt
$ ls
test.txt.gz

$ mv test.txt.gz widget.gz

$ gunzip -N widget.gz
$ ls
test.txt
```

... which is the result we were looking for.

Comment: So I'm clear... I would use `gunzip -N` to ensure the original filename is used (I'm not near the OS X box at the moment)?

Comment: I've added a test to show that the `-N` option works -- at least in Cygwin on my Windows PC.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I can confirm the results on OS X using `gunzip`.

Answer (score 3):

gzip / gunzip (version 1.6 in Linux Mint / Ubuntu) doesn't *appear* to remember or use the original filenames, but it apparently **can**. My original answer, after some basic testing, was that it didn't save the filenames, but I was *tricked* by the misleading `--list` output (probably like the OP was too).

The man page indicates that it can save & use the original filename, but even when creating a .gz file with the `-N or --name` option, when listing (`-l`) the contents of that .gz file the `uncompressed_name` column lists the current filename "base".

```
$ echo test > t1
$ gzip -vkN t1
t1: -40.0% -- replaced with t1.gz

$ gzip -vl t1.gz 
method  crc     date  time           compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
defla 3bb935c6 Jan  3 14:59                  28                   5 -40.0% t1

$ cp t1.gz N1.gz
$ gzip -vl N1.gz 
method  crc     date  time           compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
defla 3bb935c6 Jan  3 15:04                  28                   5 -40.0% N1
```

*Unless* you also use the `-N` option when testing/listing, *then* it shows the original filename

```
$ gzip -vlN t1.gz 
method  crc     date  time           compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
defla 3bb935c6 Jan  3 14:59                  28                   5 -40.0% t1
$ gzip -vlN N1.gz 
method  crc     date  time           compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
defla 3bb935c6 Jan  3 14:59                  28                   5 -40.0% t1
```

Uncompressing without using the `-N` option doesn't restore the original filename either,

I didn't think gzip ever had saved or used the original filename, it's more of a "one file at a time" compression often used for .tar files, with tar saving multiple files and their names the usefulness of gzip saving names seems limited.

Other compressed archive formats like .zip, .7z, also remember filenames, since they archive & compress multiple files, they're like a .tar.gz in one.

Speaking of crypto, gpg can remember & use original filenames (definitely when it uses it's `-c` symmetric encryption on a single file, should work for public key encryption too).

Comment: As indicated by the original question, and Simon's answer, gzip does in fact remember the original file name.  The fact that it only compresses one file is a non sequitur.

Comment: @psusi I was *tricked* by `--list`'s misleading output, updated answer with some interesting test results